# C++ Server HTTP request packet leaks? Slowing network down after 2 days

Tags: c++, sockets, http, winapi, server

I have a server I made that uses HTTP requests to post to my website and waits for a response. A function called heartbeat() in the program will continuously post to my website every 3 seconds an HTTP request.

I could not manage to get an HTTP request library so I had to look online for custom code in C++ to get it done. It works but I've found that if I leave the server up after 2 days, my network completely slows down to a halt. And yes, it's definitely my server doing this as I've been watching my network and it's completely fine if I don't have my server on for 2 days. It's the server.

I'm honestly lost at what the heck else could be causing this, **so I was wondering if someone could look at my heartbeat/http function and see if there's any flaws in it that could cause some kind of packet leaks or something that could slow down my network after 2 days since this function gets called every 3 seconds.**

http://pastebin.com/atfiwFry

```
void loop(){

    ...

    while(1){
        if(heartClock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds() >= 3){
            heartClock.restart();
            sf::Thread heartThread(std::bind(&MasterServerHandler::heartbeat_server, cst::masterIP, tcp_port, udp_port, match->num_players(), false));
            heartThread.launch();
        }
    }

}

/*
heartbeat_server: Posts a heartbeat to the master server list to let it know this server is still online.

masterServerIP: IP of the website to post HTTP request to
tcp_port: Posting the TCP port of the server to the master server list
udp_port: Posting the UDP port of the server to the master server list
curPlayers: Posting how many players are currently connected to the server
viewResponse: Whether or not we want to view the response back
*/
void MasterServerHandler::heartbeat_server(std::string masterServerIP, int tcp_port, int udp_port, int curPlayers, bool viewResponse){
    if(cst::postServer == false) return;

    std::cout << "heartbeat!" << std::endl;

    std::mutex mut;
    mut.lock();

    std::string file = "heartbeat.php";

    std::string tcp_port_s = "";
    std::string udp_port_s = "";
    std::string curPlayers_s = "";

    stringstream sPort;
    sPort << tcp_port; tcp_port_s = sPort.str(); sPort.str(std::string());
    sPort << udp_port; udp_port_s = sPort.str(); sPort.str(std::string());
    sPort << curPlayers; curPlayers_s = sPort.str(); sPort.str(std::string());

    std::string data = "?tcp_port=" + tcp_port_s + "&udp_port=" + udp_port_s + "&curPlayers=" + curPlayers_s;

    std::string response = post_data(file, data);
    if(viewResponse){
        cout << "WEB RESPONSE: " << endl;
        cout << response << endl;
    }

    mut.unlock();
}

/*
post_data: Posts data via an HTTP request
file: The file to post data to
data: The data to post

*/
std::string MasterServerHandler::post_data(std::string file, std::string data){
    string request;
    string response;
    int resp_leng;

    char buffer[BUFFERSIZE];
    struct sockaddr_in serveraddr;
    int sock;

    WSADATA wsaData;
    const char* ipaddress  = cst::masterIP.c_str();
    std::string host = cst::masterHost;

    int port = 80;

    request+="GET /masterserverlist/" + string(file) + data + " HTTP/1.0\r\n";
    request+="Host: " + host + "\r\n";
    request+="\r\n";
     //open socket


    if ((sock = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) < 0)
        cout << "WEB socket() failed" << endl;

    //connect
    memset(&serveraddr, 0, sizeof(serveraddr));
    serveraddr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipaddress);
    serveraddr.sin_port        = htons((unsigned short) port);
    if (connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *) &serveraddr, sizeof(serveraddr)) < 0)
        cout << "WEB connect() failed" << endl;

    //send request
    if (send(sock, request.c_str(), request.length(), 0) != request.length())
        cout << "WEB send() sent a different number of bytes than expected" << endl;;

    //get response
        response = "";
        resp_leng= BUFFERSIZE;
        while (resp_leng == BUFFERSIZE)
        {
            resp_leng= recv(sock, (char*)&buffer, BUFFERSIZE, 0);
            if (resp_leng>0)
                response+= string(buffer).substr(0,resp_leng);
            //note: download lag is not handled in this code
        }


    return response;

}
```

Or if anyone knows a better HTTP request function that would be great.

Comment: Have you tried using something like wireshark to analyse the traffic being created on your network?

Comment: Your network slows to a halt , meaning that everything on the network runs slowly, or just this server?

Comment: Your `post_data()` function creates a new socket every time, but never deletes it again. You're leaking sockets.

Comment: And you launch a new thread every 3 seconds, regardless of whether or not the last one has finished.

Comment: BTW I don't buy the "I couldn't find an HTTP request library". How do you think the millions of pieces of software that use HTTP work? There are _millions_ such libraries. How come you couldn't find one?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean I couldn't find one, I meant I found libraries but I just couldn't work out the errors when trying to implement it into my server, using Visual Studio Express 2012. For example, I tried cURL but there were just so many issues.

Is the launching a new thread issue what's causing this network slowdown? And yes I mean my entire network slows down. Or is this happening because I wasn't closing the socket?

Comment: Close your socket, see if it helps, come back if it doesn't.

Comment: And look into implementing a thread pool.  Or stop using threads at all. You don't really need them in this situation. Your loop has no UI. So you could just make the loop send the request directly, sleep 3 seconds, and repeat. Threading is overkill when used improperly.